# passing pipeline variable as argument into Powershell build step not working in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to be able to pass a pipeline variable into a Powershell build step in Azure DevOps Server. I'm trying to accomplish this by passing the variable as an argument.

Here is my pipeline YAML file:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Detect Subfolder Changes'
  name: setvarStep
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\detectchanges.ps1
    failOnStderr: true
  
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Get Version Number'
  name: getVersion
  inputs:
    arguments: >
      - packagepath $(setvarStep.changedPackage)
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\getversion.ps1
    failOnStderr: true
```

Here is the Powershell script (getversion.ps1) where I pass the 'packagepath' argument:

```
param($packagepath)

Write-Host "packagepath is: $packagepath"

$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content $packagepath)
$version = [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version

"##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion;isOutput=true]$version"
```

The Writ-Host command prints out 'packagepath is: -'. I turned on debugging and the argument value does show up in the log as: `##[debug]INPUT_ARGUMENTS: '- packagepath dotnet/TestPackage/*.csproj'`

Instead of passing the variable as an argument I also tried inserting the variable into the script like this: `$packagepath = $($env:SETVARSTEP.CHANGEDPACKAGE)` but it didn't work.

I did try adding double quotes to the argument parameter in the build step like this: `- packagepath "$(setvarStep.changedPackage)"`. It didn't work either.

The argument value is getting to the Powershell script, getversion.ps1 but for some reason the value is not displaying.

Comment: `- packagepath` -> `-packagepath`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@g.sulman Thanks for the suggestion. I changed - packagepath to -packagepath and it worked. I figured it was something small like the syntax.

Comment: I will once Stackoverflow allows me to accept my own answer. Thanks.